# How to globally inform sessionscoped beans to reload their data?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a session scoped bean which stores the selected employee.
An always visible input offers the ability to change the selected employee at any time.

Because there are a plenty of adjustable settings (and views) a couple of session scoped beans hold their @PostConstruct loaded data inside member variables, and I wouldn't like to reload this data from storage any time the view is opened (@ViewScoped).

I don't have an idea how to inform all active beans about the new selected employee.

Any hint is welcome ... ;)

I use Tomcat 8, Primefaces 5, JSF 2.2.

Comment: *"I wouldn't like to reload this data from storage any time the view is opened"* So you tried to solve data loading performance problem by "caching" entities in HTTP session in frontend instead of in e.g. 2nd level JPA cache in backend? You're indeed shooting yourself in the foot this way.

Comment: :D You're right :D but this is simply a huge lack of knowledge after programming jsf for approximately one year. I will add "JPA cache" to my brain and return here if I have a solution. Or mabye you know a link on the fly to startup JPA before I start googleling? ;)

Comment: @BalusC it took a bit of time, switched to JPA and my feet are still efficient ... :D ... If you leave an appropriate answer I can tag as the accepted one ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to reload this data every time the page is loaded, you could at least search the selected employee and if it's the same, do the update. If not, you don't need to do a thing.

Comment: I was thinking about something simular, a kind of dirty buffer flag. Maybe this could be an intermediate solution until I know how to implement an useful backend cache - like BalusC suggested ...

Answer (score 0):

Please notice: this solution is a **workaround** for a poor design!

The design insufficiency is to cache the data inside a session scoped backing bean instead of using 2nd level JPA cache in backend (see comment BalusC on question).

The workaround:
my session scoped SessionManager keeps the selectedPerson. On changing this selection a timestamp is updated:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionManager implements Serializable {

  private Date lastUpdateSelectedPerson;  // +getter

  public void setSelectedPerson(Person selectedPerson) {
    this.selectedPerson = selectedPerson;
    lastUpdateSelectedPerson = new Date();
  }
}
```

Hence other backing beans may compare this timestamp to a local update timestamp:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyData implements Serializable {

  @Inject SessionManager sessionManager;
  private Date lastUpdateData;

  private void updateData() {
    // update data
    lastUpdateData = sessionManager.getLastUpdateSelectedPerson();
  }

  public List<Data> getData() {
    if (sessionManager.getLastUpdateSelectedPerson().compareTo(lastUpdateData) > 0)
            updateData;
        return data;
    }
}
```